Jakarta Mail throws: Not provider of jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider was found
I am new to Jakarta Mail and trying out a standalone test program but I am get the following error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not provider of jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider
I use the following to run at the command line in Windows
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-21\bin\java -classpath .;jakarta.mail-api-2.1.0.jar;jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar TestEmail
The program is a simple one I copied from internet.
I compiled using the following on the command line
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-21\bin\javac -classpath .;jakarta.mail-api-2.1.0.jar;jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar TestEmail.java
import jakarta.mail.*;
import jakarta.mail.internet.*;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestEmail {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        
        String to = "sendToMailAddress";
        String from = "sendFromMailAddress";
        
        String host = "smtp.yourisp.invalid";

        // Create properties, get Session
        Properties props = new Properties();

Any help will be much appreciated.
Peter

This question is similar to: getting IllegalStateException when getting instance of jakarta.mail.Session object. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The suggested question is related to Maven which I don't really understand at this point. Thanks anyways. The other answer has help solved my question.

JSYK the link provided in comments, couldn't resolve my issue with same exception as above, the below answer by @life888888 did.

Remove api jar

jakarta.mail-api-2.1.0.jar
jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar

Because the official jakarta mail api does not provide complete implementation.
just use this one: com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:2.0.1
is enough.
Download Implementation jar
Maven
pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>

or download only 2 files:

jakarta.mail-2.0.1.jar (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/mail/jakarta.mail/2.0.1/jakarta.mail-2.0.1.jar)
jakarta.activation-2.0.1.jar (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/activation/jakarta.activation/2.0.1/jakarta.activation-2.0.1.jar)

your javac
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-21\bin\javac -classpath .;jakarta.mail-2.0.1.jar;jakarta.activation-2.0.1.jar TestEmail.java

run
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-21\bin\java -classpath .;jakarta.mail-2.0.1.jar;jakarta.activation-2.0.1.jar TestEmail

Update - NOTE
Why do some answers tell us to add jakarta.mail-api and some answers tell us to add com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail?
If you are developing Jakarta Web (war), then add the following:
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>

Run command:
mvn dependency:tree

get result:
[INFO] \- jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO]    \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.3:compile

then build
mvn clean package

get hello.war (my example)
Test On Server: wildfly-33.0.1.Final
wildfly provides a complete Jakarta EE Server implementation (including mail), so only adding the above dependent content can send emails.
Test On Server: apache-tomcat-10.1.28
Tomcat does not provide a complete Jakarta EE Server implementation, so adding only the above dependencies will result in an error message:
No provider of jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider was found</p><p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.</p><p><b>Exception</b></p><pre>java.lang.IllegalStateException: No provider of jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider was found
    jakarta.mail.util.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:61)
    jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider.provider(StreamProvider.java:199)
    jakarta.mail.Session.&lt;init&gt;(Session.java:257)
    jakarta.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:310)
    com.example.HelloMailServlet.doGet(HelloMailServlet.java:40)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:5

Therefore, the same war file will have different results when deployed to Wildfly and Tomcat. Tomcat does not provide a complete Jakarta EE implementation, so some implementations are often missing. Therefore, we need to add additional implementations. library for tomcat war.
Since Java Application is not a Jakarta EE Server, it naturally does not have an implementation of Jakarta EE, so we directly use the jar that implements jakarta mail.
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>

(The War file deployed to Tomcat is also changed to add this Jar.)
in conclusion:

If your program is to be deployed in an environment with a complete Jakarta EE implementation (Wildfly Server),

please add:
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>


If your program is intended for use without a complete Jakarta EE implementation (Standalone Java Application, Tomcat Server),

please add:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>


This solves my problem. Thank you so much!

FYI. There was a typo in older versions of JakartaMail of "Not provider..." vs. in 2.1.3 the "No provider...".  If you see the word "Not" instead of "No" you for sure have an older version of JakartaMail.
